# Using Throw within ParallelDo

Tags: parallelization, procedural-programming

I've noticed that I can't Throw from within a ParallelDo in the same way that I can from inside Do. For instance, the following will work as anticipated with Do but not with ParallelDo:

```
Catch[ParallelDo[num=RandomInteger[{1,5}];Print[num];If[num==2,Throw[i]],{i,10}]]
```

It generates errors of the following form:

> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[7] returned to top level.
>
> ParallelDeveloperQueueRun::hmm: Received unexpected result Hold[Throw[7]] from KernelObject[4,local].

As I read it, the Catch isn't passed to the servant kernels, so when the servant kernels try to Throw, they get confused. Meanwhile, the main kernel just receives a Throw[i] and doesn't know how to evaluate it.

**Is there any way to have the servant kernels just serve the results no matter what and have the main kernel check the Catch/Throw?**

I could probably emulate this by having the servant kernels running Abort in place of Throw, but this feels more like a hack.

This is not unrelated to the problem discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-to-collect-result-continuously-interruptible-calculation-when-running-para/329#329), but I only need to return a specific result (the one that I'd like to trigger Throw) rather than all results calculated so far, and I'm working with ParallelDo instead of Table, which I think means it's safely interruptible anyway (see David's answer to the linked question using Abort).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the goal is to perform a parallel search for the first result that meets some condition, then we can consider using [ParallelTry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTry.html) instead of throw/catch:

```
ParallelTry[If[PrimeQ[#], #, $Failed]&, Range[492114, 500000]]

(* 492227 *)
```

This evaluates a function for every value in the second argument (in parallel).  The first result that is anything other than `$Failed` is returned immediately, and all other parallel computations are quietly aborted.

If all evaluations fail, a warning is issued along with the result `$Failed`:

```
ParallelTry[If[PrimeQ[#], #, $Failed]&, Range[492114, 492226]]

(* ParallelTry::toofew: Only 0 results received, rather than 1. >>
   $Failed *)
```

We can also ask for more than one result to be returned:

```
ParallelTry[If[PrimeQ[#], #, $Failed]&, Range[492113, 500000], 2]

(* {492113,492227} *)
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'm playing with this approach. The difficulty is that I define several auxiliary variables on each try, so I think I'll need to restructure somewhat, but it should probably work (and it might even be more efficient).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to my answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76691/18476) you probably have to redesign your code. Depending on your need

```
Module[{counter = 1},
 ParallelDo[
  While[2 != (num = RandomInteger[{1, 15}]) && counter <= 10, counter++; Print[num]];
  If[counter <= 10, Print["Thrown at trial " <> ToString[counter]]], {$ProcessorCount}]]
```

or

```
Module[{counter = 1},
 ParallelTry[
  While[2 != (num = RandomInteger[{1, 15}]) && counter <= 10, counter++; Print[num]];
  If[counter <= 10, Print["Thrown at trial " <> ToString[counter]]], {$ProcessorCount}]];
```

should work. The first one returning as many results as `ProcessorCount` and the second one only returning the result first found.

Comment: Looking at the second one, is the counter being shared across the servant kernels or does each servant have its own? If the former, I can probably use Monitor to track it. I'm not sure about the latter.

Comment: Each kernel has its own counter. It is not shared.

Comment: @Shane If you want to use `Monitor`, you can remove the `Module`, set `counter = 0;` as a global variable and share it among the kernels by executing `SetSharedVariable[counter]`. Now `Monitor` will work.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I had in mind also. I guess having local counters minimizes the communication to make it more efficient, but it's also nice to have the global counter. I'm testing this solution and WReach's.